# Gold Tag Badge criteria is based partially on language popularity

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

The criteria for obtaining a [Gold Tag Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) is

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the tag

More popular tags attract more answers, and potential for more upvotes, which are needed to count toward the 1000 total score requirement.

I live mainly in [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), which is much less popular than [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). I will demonstrate how the system is a bit broken.

Currently, there are [652 C# Gold Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/c-sharp), but only [20 VB.NET Gold Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/154/vb-net). Only 8 have been awarded for VB.NET in the past 5 years, and 4 of those users haven't posted an answer in over 6 months. There have been 320+ gold badges awarded for C# in the past 5 years.

I admit that my motivation here is partially in my own self-interest. I have [499 answers in the vb.net tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a832052%20%5bvb.net%5d%20is%3aanswer), so I am well above the 200 answer threshold. However, my highest voted answer has only +6/-0, and I like to believe this is not for lack of quality answers (though you may disagree).

Looking at the most recent recipient of the vb.net gold badge, that user has [1230 answers in the vb.net tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A584183+%5Bvb.net%5D+is%3Aanswer) and I guess it took that user around 1000 answers to be awarded the badge. That user's highest voted answer is similar to mine in that it has only +7/-0. The badge was awarded in March 2019.

Contrast with C#. The most recent recipient has only [300 answers in the C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a626442%20%5bc%23%5d%20is%3aanswer). The badge was awarded one week ago. The user's highest voted question is +124/-0. So it takes roughly 1/4 to 1/3 the number of answers to be awarded the C# badge vs. VB.NET.

It must be even worse for languages less popular than VB.NET (yes, I believe they exist).

The gold badge allows one to single-handedly close a question with that tag. I *know* I have enough knowledge of the langue to be able to single-handledly close or reopen questions. Someone at a level similar to me in C# would already have this privilege. Should this really be based on language popularity? I believe there is also the fact that older answers are seen more and people answering questions 10 years ago have a better chance to get the badge now, than currently active users. So the longer you are here, the higher chance you'll have to get this privilege. That doesn't necessarily speak to your ability.

Would it make more sense to award this badge based on number of positively received answers with that tag?

Comment: I mean... the more active a tag is, the more gold badgers that are needed to fulfill the task.

Comment: @KevinB of course there's that. But the badge is rewarded partly as a consequence of the tag popularity. Why should two people with the same ability in different languages not be rewarded the same way? I'm just wondering if there's a better way to hand out this badge.

Comment: well... there's certainly *some* things that can be done, such as giving out badges based on having, say, 200 posts scored positively, which would certainly increase the number of gold badgers on lower traffic tags, but it would increase the number on high traffic ones far more than that, as you'd expect... which... may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Side note: if you are looking for more unpleasant comments and accusations there are other ways to get them rather than waiting for gold-hammer...

Comment: Once (if?) the 3-votes-to-close proposal gets implemented permanently, it should make things a *bit* easier, but the fundamental problem remains

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for finding the dupe. I promise I searched but couldn't find it. It's slightly different, but the same premise. Someone had some good ideas back in 2014, but nothing happened I guess...